# Use jQuery to reference an anchor tag in the same div as self

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function that binds the click event of any element on my page with the class name 'foo'.

```
$('.foo').click(function () { etc.
```

Whilst inside this function I want to reference another element that exists alongside the currently bound element - inside the same div but with the class name 'bar'.

How do I go about referencing 'bar' based on it's proximity, within the same div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the elements are at same level you can use siblings i.e.:

```
$(this).siblings(".bar")
```

If the hierarchy is different then try this:

```
$(this).closest("div").find(".bar")
```

Answer (score 2):

**Like this if bar is the next sibling after foo:**

```
<div>
   <div class="foo"></div>
   <div class="bar"></div>
</div>

$('.foo').click(function () { 
  var bar = $(this).next('.bar');
});
```

**Like this if bar is the previous sibling after foo:**

```
<div>
   <div class="bar"></div>
   <div class="foo"></div>
</div>

$('.foo').click(function () { 
  var bar = $(this).prev('.bar');
});
```

**Like this if bar can be either the previous or next sibling of foo:**

```
$('.foo').click(function () { 
  var bar = $(this).siblings('.bar');
});
```

OR

```
$('.foo').click(function () { 
  var bar = $('bar', $(this).parent());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('.bar', this)` <-- like that (if `bar` is within `foo`)

`$(this).closest('.bar')` <-- like that (if `bar` is near `foo`)

Comment: just remember jQuery.closest() will not get .bar if it is a sibling.  closest() only searches ancestors.